# Problems with an application that sends SMS

Tags: vb.net

I have an application to send SMS every time someone registers in the system.

My problem is that when 2 users register simultaneously, the system does not send the corresponding SMS

For example, of 120 users who registered, only 110 received the confirmation SMS.

The SMS was sent from this application, using a HUAWEI E3131 Modem which I have via USB and configure it as a modem.

How do I prevent any message from being queued?

```vb
Dim lockObject as New Object()

SyncLock lockObject

    TextBoxMODEM.Clear() 'NUEVO MENSAJE

    SerialPort1.Write("AT" & vbCrLf) 'COMPRUEBA LA CONEXION CON EL MODEM

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

    SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf) 'INDICA QUE VA A ENVIAR SMS

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

    SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TelefonoTextBox.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf) 'ENVIARA EL MENSAJE SIN ALMACENAMIENTO

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

    SerialPort1.Write(Mensaje.ToString & Chr(26)) ' ENVIA EL MENSAJE

End SyncLock
```

Comment: Why wouldn’t you queue the messages in the app if you know it takes time to send an sms message.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use an object to synchronize access to a critical section of code. However, all the threads should see the same object. If you are declaring it right above the SyncLock, then you should either

Make it locally static using the Static keyword in VB.NET to synchronize access on *the same* instance

```vb
Class A
    Sub B
        Static lockObject as New Object()
        SyncLock lockObject
```

Or declare it as an instance field at the class level to synchronize access on *the same* instance

```vb
Class A
    Private lockObject as New Object()
    Sub B
        SyncLock lockObject
```

Or declare it as a static field using the Shared keyword in VB.NET to synchronize access to *all* instances

```vb
Class A
    Shared lockObject as New Object()
    Sub B
        SyncLock lockObject
```

If you have multiple instances which need to synchronize access to one block, then use the third option. The first two are useful when each instance needs to be synchronized, for example you may have one serial port per instance which does not interfere with other instances' ports.

Queuing is not a bad idea in any case.

Comment: Do you think this configuration on my serial port can solve my problem?
         SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
        SerialPort.DtrEnable = True
        SerialPort.RtsEnable = True
        SerialPort.NewLine = vbCrLf                                                                                               anyway, how would the solution be implementing queues and tasks,